# How to Handle Mutiple Model Bound Forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, fluentvalidation

I am buiding a UI screen for editing the details of an Ecommerce Order.  The model for my view (OrderModel) has everything I need (in properties that are also ViewModels), but the UI isn't designed to be able to edit all of it at once.

For example, one part of the UI is for customer data..another for order details, and another for tracking information, each having their own "Save" buttons.

I realize that I could use one giant form and use hidden form fields to populate the non-editable fields, making each "Save" button post all the data, but that smells bad.

I'd like to segment the editable chunks into smaller ViewModels that are posted and validated individually while retaining the strong typing but I'm unsure of how to achieve this in MVC3. Will I need partial views that are called from the primary view?

FYI, I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor syntax and client side FluentValidation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial Views are a good solution. You can pass different ViewModels to each partial view.  But if only sections of the overall view are updated at a time I would not do a post back on the whole page. Instead I would use Ajax calls using JQuery/Javascript to update the individual information back to the controller.  I would also look into something like Knockout.js to handle the data binding on the page.

Comment: I second that - I would use ajax loading of the partials